# How to set up an ASP.NET site with installshield 2010?

Tags: asp.net, iis, installshield

I'm creating an installer for an ASP.NET app, and everything seems to work fine until I run the setup file, it creates all the folders and all the IIS stuff, BUT I keep getting a parse error from the asp page when I try to load it. The page itself is fine, because if I Copy-Paste-Replace the folder that contains the web page with the one Visual Studio generates (the sourse folder from wich installshield is getting the page to put into the installer) I no longer get the parser error (even though the code line it aparently can't read is still there). So I'm gessing that installshield is doing something to my page :S

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've done this many times.  What is the parser error?  Does it say that the page is not precompiled?

Comment: Yes, that's right! Here is the exact error:  

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_masterpage.master.cd9aefd4'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ master language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Master_Page_MasterPage, App_Web_masterpage.master.cd9aefd4" enabletheming="true" %>

Comment: In my experience, it means that you didn't deploy all files into the /bin directory.  Did you deploy all files with the .Compiled extension?

Comment: owww man, forgot to check that... Yes, there were some .dll missing that was making all the trouble. Thanks!! :)